# Email before download, fill form once download document

Tags: php, wordpress, download

The warning on point 5 of downloads page is a plugin error. I did log a support ticket about this but it has not had a response - https://wordpress.org/support/topic/email-before-download-error-php/

I use a Email before download plugin, Contact form 7 plugin.

We need a popup form to appear when you click a download button (it is doing this now). but then if you want to download a 2nd or 3rd document in the same session, you shouldn’t have to fill out the form again as all the details will be the same and it would be very annoying to the customer so the user should be allowed to download as many documents as they want, after entering the details after the first download.

How do I do this?

Comment: its purely plugin related issue, better contact plugin provider, and if you want to populate fields, use session or cookie

Comment: @charankumar I haven't heard anything from plugin provider. How do I do use session or cookie for download documents? Or is there different plugin like email before download?